# Android - Testing Nested Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Am I doing this correctly, I am trying to have a nested fragments with No relative progress. The first onCreateView contains its view, but in side that onCreateView I instantiated a new class that extends a fragment and also have its own onCreateView and xml. I am getting errors now. I just wanted to display the `VideoPlayerFragment` into the first Main View. Hoping to learn more.

```
public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_main_menu_activity, container, false);
        //Bundle args = getArguments();

       Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.testLayout, videoFragment).commit();
       //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
             //   Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**VideoPlayerFragment**

public class VideoPlayerFragment extends Fragment {

```
  public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.id.testLayout, container, false);
      Bundle args = getArguments();
     //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
           //   Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
      return rootView;
  }
```

}

**testing_fragments**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.jinisys.restoplusordering.VideoPlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lommeregnerv2">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/testLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>

 </fragment>
```

LogCat:

```
07-15 19:27:30.391: E/FragmentManager(8218): Activity state:
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040039 type #0x12 is not valid
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at com.jinisys.restoplusordering.VideoPlayerFragment.onCreateView(VideoPlayerFragment.java:17)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1481)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-15 19:37:44.885: E/AndroidRuntime(8654):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's up with that layout file? You can't have a fragment tag  wrapping other elements. Also, where do you use that layout file?

Comment: the layout is just used for testing, I am just experimenting if this will work, but don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Clean your project. Also the `inflate()` method of the `LayoutInflater` expects a resource in the form of `R.layout.theLayout`(a layout file reference) and not a `R.id.testLayout` like you use.

Comment: Its look like there some problem with container, you are adding fragment to, check, whether  you correctly specifying the container id, i.e the layout file you are inflating has the specified viewgroup container

Comment: Yes, I have to put  a `FrameLayout ` inside the `load_main_menu_activity` xml and delete the `testing_fragments`- this xml makes the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again @Luksprog for the hint, I figure it out my self. Since I wanted to have a nested fragment I should need a parent xml to add this code below. This code enables me to add another fragment inside a fragment.

```
<FrameLayout 

            android:id="@+id/fragg"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```